# Cognitive OCR service stopped working from JapanEast Region

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, vision

Problem is from using Cognitive OCR service from web application, suddenly stopped working from 23rd, services in southeastasia is working fine, problem with japaneast and japanwest regions. 
(Note: Services are working using Postman from japaneast region and not working using Web App)

There is no problem if i use Cognitive Service from southeastasia region. Problem is with JapanEast and JapanWest regions

Exception Message(from japaneast region): **The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send** 
Does any one faced similar issue.

Comment: "Note: Services are working using Postman from japaneast region and not working using Web App" << tested with the same `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`?

Comment: Same problem today with westeurope :\